# Does static variables in a class persist for the whole lifetime of a request?

Tags: php, static

For example,

```
class Foo
{
    private static $my_static;

    public static function staticValue() {
        if (self::$my_static === null) {
            self::$my_static = 'foo';
        }
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}
```

The first call of `Foo::staticValue()` will set `$my_static` to `foo`, and the subsequent calls of `Foo::staticValue()` will not go into the body of the `if` statement but return `foo` right away. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct, in this context static is defined as once per script run.

Edit: that is, static initialization, is defined once per script run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.